# undefined method `accepted_user_friendships'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, undefined, nomethoderror

NoMethodError in UserFriendshipsController#index
undefined method `accepted_user_friendships'

I'm getting the above error message when clicking on the '**accepted**' link within my index.html page. All the other links function properly except this one. Thanks in advance. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**user_friendships_controller**

```
class UserFriendshipsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  respond_to :html, :json

  def index
    @user_Friendships = UserFriendshipDecorator.decorate_collection(friendship_association.all)
    respond_with @user_Friendships
  end   

  def accept
    @user_friendship = current_user.user_friendships.find(params[:id])
    if @user_friendship.accept_mutual_friendship!
    @user_friendship.friend.user_friendships.find_by(friend_id: current_user.id).accept_mutual_friendship!
    flash[:success] = "You are now friends with #{@user_friendship.friend.name}!"
    redirect_to user_friendships_path
    else
    flash[:error] = "That friendship could not be accepted."
    end
  end

  def block
    @user_friendship = current_user.user_friendships.find(params[:id])
    if @user_friendship.block!
      flash[:success] = "You have blocked #{@user_friendship.friend.name}."
    else
      flash[:error] = "This friendship could not be blocked."
    end
    redirect_to user_friendships_path
  end

  def new
    if params[:friend_id]
      @friend = User.find(params[:friend_id]).first
      raise ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound if @friend.nil?
      @user_friendship = current_user.user_friendships.new(friend: @friend)
    else
      flash[:error] = "Friend required."
    end
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    render file: 'public/404', status: :not_found
  end

  def create
    if params[:user_friendship] && params[:user_friendship].has_key?(:friend_id)
      @friend = User.find(params[:user_friendship][:friend_id])
      @user_friendship = UserFriendship.request(current_user, @friend)
      respond_to do |format|
        if @user_friendship.new_record?
          format.html do
            flash[:error] = "There was a problem creating this friend request."
            redirect_to user_path(@friend)
          end
          format.json { render json: @user_friendship.to_json, status: :precondition_failed }
        else
            format.html do
              flash[:success] = "Friend request sent."
              redirect_to user_path(@friend)
            end
            format.json { render json: @user_friendship.to_json }
          end
        end
    else
        flash[:error] = "Friend required"
        redirect_to root_path
    end
  end

  def edit
    @friend = User.find(params[:id])
    @user_friendship = current_user.user_friendships.find_by(friend_id: @friend.id).decorate
  end

  def destroy
    @user_friendship = current_user.user_friendships.find(params[:id])
    if @user_friendship.destroy
      flash[:success] = "Your friendship was deleted"
    end  
    redirect_to user_friendships_path
  end

  def user_friendship
    params.require(:user_friendship).permit(:user_id, :friend_id, :user, :friend, :state, :user_friendship)
  end  

  private
  def friendship_association
    case params[:list]
    when nil
      current_user.user_friendships
    when 'blocked'
      current_user.blocked_user_friendships
    when 'pending'
      current_user.pending_user_friendships
    when 'accepted'
      current_user.accepted_user_friendships
    when 'requested'
      current_user.requested_user_friendships
    end
  end
end
```

**Index.html**

```
<div class="page-header">
<h1> Friends </h1>
</div>

<div>
  <strong>Friend list:</strong>
  <%= link_to 'Accepted', user_friendships_path(list: 'accepted') %>
  <%= link_to 'Pending', user_friendships_path(list: 'pending') %>
  <%= link_to 'Requested', user_friendships_path(list: 'requested') %>
  <%= link_to 'Blocked', user_friendships_path(list: 'blocked') %>
</div>

   <% @user_Friendships.each do |friendship| %>
      <% friend = friendship.friend %>
      <div id="<%= dom_id(friendship) %>" class="friend row">
       <div class="span1">

       </div>
       <div class="span7">
         <strong><%= friend.name %></strong><br />
            <%if friendship.pending? %>
            <em>Friendship is pending.</em> <%=link_to "Delete request", edit_user_friendship_path(friendship.friend) %>.
            <% end %>
            <% if friendship.requested? %>
                <em>Friendship requested.</em> <%=link_to "Accept Friendship", edit_user_friendship_path(friendship.friend) %>.
            <% end %>
            <% if friendship.accepted? %>
                <em>Friendship started <%= friendship.updated_at %>.</em> <%= link_to "Update friendship", edit_user_friendship_path(friendship.friend) %>.
            <% end %>
           </div>
       </div>
   <% end %>
```

Comment: Check `current_user` is not `nil`. If not, then check the source code for that `current_user`, probably the class `User`. If not successful, *then* go to SO.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. I forgot to add the below code into my user model. That was a complete miss on my part.

```
has_many :accepted_user_friendships, class_name: 'UserFriendship',
                                      foreign_key: :user_id,
                                      conditions: { state: 'accepted' }
has_many :accepted_friends, through: :pending_user_friendships, source: :friend
```